# Direct ByteBuffers in Thrift with Finagle

Tags: thrift, finagle, twitter-finagle

We currently use thrift server for our RPC.  One of the calls we wish to support wants to return the result of reading a file into a direct ByteBuffer.  THRIFT-883 says this isn't supported (cause the ByteBuffer.array() isn't supported), so was wondering if we could support direct ByteBuffers if we switched to finagle?

Does finagle overcome this limitation or is it also faced with it?

Example code:

Thrift

```
struct BlockRequest {
  1: i64 blockId,
  2: i64 offset,
  3: i64 len
}

struct BlockResponse {
  1: i64 blockId
  2: i64 offset
  3: i64 len
  4: binary data
}

service DataService {
  BlockResponse requestBlock(1: BlockRequest request)
    throws (1: BlockInfoException bie, 2: FileDoesNotExistException fdne)
}
```

Java

```
  @Override
  public BlockResponse requestBlock(BlockRequest request) throws BlockInfoException,
      FileDoesNotExistException, TException {

    final long blockId = request.blockId;
    final long offset = request.offset;
    final long len = request.len;
...

    final RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "r");
    long fileLength = file.length();
    final long readLen;
    if (len == -1) {
      readLen = fileLength - offset;
    } else {
      readLen = len;
    }

    FileChannel channel = file.getChannel();
    final MappedByteBuffer data = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, offset, readLen);

    final BlockResponse response = new BlockResponse();
    response.setBlockId(blockId);
    response.setOffset(offset);
    response.setLen(readLen);
    response.setData(data);

    return response
...
```

Comment: Can you add some code to demonstrate the problem you are facing? Have you tested the patch? BTW, [THRIFT-833](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-833) says nothing about ByteBuffers, but [THRIFT-883](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-883) does. Typo?

Comment: Sorry, 883 is the correct one

Comment: Added the code that shows this problem.  The patch is to copy the data on heap into a byte array.  I am currently doing that locally in the code.

Answer (score 0):

> Won't be able to use thrift this, since the file could be large.

The real question is: Is it a good idea to put a potentially large file completely in one chunk over the wire? Your service already defines the ability to deliver a file in chunks, and exactly that would have been my proposal. Sure, you will have to copy the files into memory at some point, but this will be the case even if you just use raw sockets: At some point the data need to be in memory.

To protect against large blocks, limit the allowed maximum length. Whether you throw an exception for oversized requests or just indicate the server-side limitation in `BlockResponse` somehow (to allow the client to clearly distinguish between EOF and limit) is a matter of taste. I'd probably use the latter approach to prevent from unnecessary extra roundtrips.